# Is there a $\sigma$-finite measure such that for an uncountable set $X$, $\mu(X)$ is infinite?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be an **uncountable** set and $\mathscr{A}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ of all subsets of X (power set of $X$, $\mathscr{P}(X)$). Is there a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ on $(X,\mathscr{A})$ such that $\mu (X)$ is **infinite**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a countably infinite subset $S$ of $X$, and let $\mu(A)$ be the cardinality of $A \cap S$.

Comment: Thanks. But I am still confused. For $X = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$, do we know $\forall~i \in \mathbb{N}$, $\mu(A_i) = |A_i \cap S| < \infty$?

Comment: If $S = \{s_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$, let $A_i = \{s_{i-1}\}$ for $i \ge 2$ and $A_1= S^c$.